# Luigi tasks and wrapper failing

Tags: python, luigi

Have asked a similar question, but decided to breakdown my pipeline into fewer steps to get a deeper understanding of where I am going wrong and to make debugging as easy as possible.

With my first class I am taking a huge csv and separating it to multiple csvs based on the user's current state. I then created another task that then looks at whether or not a given user moved from one state to the next returning 1's and 0's depending on whether or not this happened.

I then have a wrapper class that should dynamically assign parameter values to the previous class. However, my pipeline does not seem to be running and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Here is what I have:

separate_csv.py:

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
class data_filter(luigi.Task):
    file = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        for current in actions:
            file_pd = pd.read_csv(self.file)
            actions = file_pd.state.unique()
            filter_file = file_pd.loc[file_pd.state.str.contains(current,na=False)]
            filter_file.to_csv('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/'+str(current)+'.csv')
    def requires(self):
        return []
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/complete.csv')
```

state_to_state_transitions.py:

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import separate_csv as sep
class state_to_state(luigi.Task):
    first_file = luigi.Parameter()
    second_file = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        #iterate through states and find probability of anonymous id existing in next state
        path = '/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'
        first = pd.read_csv(path+self.first_file)
        second = pd.read_csv(path+self.second_file)
        first['probability'] = first.anonymous_id.isin(second.anonymous_id).astype(int)
        #save anonymous id along with probability (1,0) of whether or not it exists in the next state
        with self.output().open('w') as out_csv:
            out_csv.write(first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file[:-4]+'to'+self.second_file)))
    def requires(self):
        files_two = [sep.data_filter(file='/Users/emm/Desktop/Attribution/finalcleanattributiondata.csv')]
        return files_two
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file[:-4]+'to'+self.second_file))
```

wrapper.py

```
import state_to_state_transitions2 as sst
import pandas as pd
import luigi
class wrapper(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        files = ['Session.csv', 'lead.csv', 'opportunity.csv', 'complete.csv']
        task_list = []
        for i in range(1, len(files)):
            task_list.append(sst.state_to_state(first_file=files[i-1],second_file=files[i]))
        return task_list
    def run(self):
        print('Wrapper ran')
        pd.DataFrame().to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/wrangler1.csv')
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/wrangler1.csv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.build([wrapper()],workers=8,local_scheduler=True)
```

Here are parts of my error message:

```
      File "/Users/emm/Documents/GitHub/AttributionModel/Capstone/state_to_state_transitions2.py", line 15, in run
    out_csv.write(first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file[:-4]+'to'+self.second_file)))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   state_to_state_lead_csv_opportunity_csv_b31ac9d110   has status   FAILED
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
DEBUG: There are 4 pending tasks possibly being run by other workers
DEBUG: There are 4 pending tasks unique to this worker
DEBUG: There are 4 pending tasks last scheduled by this worker
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=152474850, workers=1, host=Emms-MacBook-Pro.local, username=***, pid=***) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 5 tasks of which:
* 1 present dependencies were encountered:
    - 1 data_filter(file=/Users/emm/Desktop/Attribution/finalcleanattributiondata.csv)
* 3 failed:
    - 3 state_to_state(first_file=Session.csv, second_file=lead.csv) ...
* 1 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 had failed dependencies:
        - 1 wrapper()

This progress looks :( because there were failed tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
with self.output().open('w') as out_csv:
    out_csv.write(first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv('/Users/emm/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file[:-4]+'to'+self.second_file)))
```

Instead of having `first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv(file_name)` which writes to file `file_name`, you need to have `first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv()`, which returns a string with the csv data.

So overall, you should have:

```
with self.output().open('w') as out_csv:
    out_csv.write(first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv())
```